# How to expose Svelte application using Apache2/IP address?

Tags: nginx, svelte

Help , I have svelte application running on localhost on port 5000 with backend express running on port 3000, and postgresql as database on port 5432.

I tried modifying /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, installing and configuring nginx to expose running application to internet, based on research on available tutorial via googling, but not yet succeeded

I need the app to run like http://168.xx.xx.xx:5000 as example , I already shared my ssh key to my boss for accessing my apps

please help/any hint, i'm using ubuntu 18.04 :)

Thank you

Comment: @Pandurang yes sir , i need to deploy/expose svelte as frontend so that my boss can access it via internet

Comment: This is not related to svelte, svelte is just a script that runs on the web page. He does not run 'svelte' but nodejs that runs express.

Comment: @mr. dolk but the backend which is express.js is running on localhost (my computer) , and i expose only my frontend which is svelte. I need to expose the frontend part so that my boss can interact with my apps (add/delete data)

Comment: It's still only a configuration issue on you local machine. You want others to access your webapplication via `http(s)://<you-up-address>:5000`. Usually it should work out of the box. Try to connect from a different machine to that and check the http error codes, if any. Maybe it's firewall issue and you're port is not accessible from outside.

Comment: @Mr. dolk yes sir , thank you for the answer. i'll try to access my app with my friend's laptop. please give hint again about the SSH , because my boss have asked about my ssh key at first , is there a way to access my app via SSH? please hint about link/search keyword. Thank you Mr Dolk :)

Comment: I hope he didn't ask for your private ssh key. No, he wouldn't need your key to access the page. Even if it was an https connection. The SSH key could be used by him to log into your computer as yourself (danger) or to authenticate as yourself with some services, like github (danger). I doubt that he'd need your public SSH key to test your app. Unless the app itself has some encryption or whatever.

Comment: You need to expose your svelte html and build (js, css ..) as a static asset on the internet. You can try netlify first if you are not able to use nginx  to serve your static assets.

Comment: @Mr Dolk , thank you sir for the complete explanation. Now I know better about sharing my SSH key. I've tried using my friend's laptop , but have not yet succeded too. I'm trying to deploy using cloud services like heroku now. Thank you sir , I really appreciated to you sharing precious knowledge. Good day sir :)

Comment: @voscausa yes sir , i'll try that . I have already build my app and try cloud services too. Thank you sir for sharing precious knowledge. Have a great day :)